# Disable Repeated System Alerts in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

On iOS 7, there is a feature under `Cellular` in Settings called: `Use Cellular Data For:`. This lists all of the apps I have on my iPhone 4 with individual On/Off Switches to disable or enable cellular data. So, I disable it on several of my apps, one of which being **Music**. When I open my Music app, it tells me…

> **Cellular Data is Turned Off for "Music"**
>   You can turn on cellular data for this app in Settings.

This alert does not occur once, but **every time** I clear the Music app from my multitasking and re-open it. Is there a way to dismiss this alert once and forever?

The alert looks something like this, but for Music:

[image]

Comment: See also the huge thread at the official Apple forums https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5433258

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can't be done at the moment. [There's no option to disable the alert](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4146), other than enabling cellular data.

If you're jailbroken, you can install [**NoAnnoyance**](https://github.com/pNre/NoAnnoyance):

> ## <sub><sub>[image]</sub></sub> NoAnnoyance
>
> #### Tame iOS annoying alerts!
>
> **A CydiaSubstrate tweak to disable annoying iOS 7 messages.**
>
> Supported alerts:
>
> - Cellular data is not enabled
> - Disable airplane mode to access data
> - Turn Off Airplane Mode or Use Wi-Fi to Access Data
> - Location accuracy improved by enabling Wi-Fi
> - Unsupported charging accessory
> - Accessory unreliable
> - Low battery
> - Cellular data is turned off for "AppName" disabled
> - Low disk space
> - The mail server is not responding
> - More...

If you wish for a non-jailbreak solution, you can provide feedback to Apple regarding this at the following page:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html

---

Possible solution provided by Parasprite — I can't get it to work:

> After some trial and error, it seems as if it becomes permanent after a few tries.
>
> 1. Turn cellular data off for the offending app ([Music]).
> 2. Open [Music], dismiss warning.
> 3. Close app using the app switcher (double-click home button and swipe off of screen).
> 4. Re-open [Music], dismiss popup.
> 5. Goto step 3, repeat until it stops showing.
>
> If it's behaviour is anything like The Game Center popup, it should be permanent after 3 dismissals.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. Jailbreaking seems to be the only available solution as of now.

Comment: Are there any updates on this question? I don't want to Jailbreak my iphone but I can't stand these messages!

Comment: @user4050 AFAIK nothing's changed and nothing appears to have changed in the iOS 8 betas regarding this

Comment: I just used [Pangu](http://en.pangu.io) to jailbreak my iPhone 6 running iOS 8.1. Worked perfectly, and I was able to install NoAnnoyance by following the instructions at the bottom of the [NoAnnoyance documentation](https://github.com/pNre/NoAnnoyance). A year of these annoying alerts turned me from someone who thought it was foolish to jailbreak into an enthusiastic jailbreaker.

Comment: For those unfamiliar with app switcher, you swipe the item upwards to remove it. Solution # 2 seems to be working for the moment, +1.

Answer (score 1):

If the popup only occurs after you clear Music from your multitasking, you could simply avoid doing that.

I know I can't convince inveterate app quitters, but the multitasking on iOS really does all the handling of RAM just fine.

Comment: While this would help users with an iPhone 5 or 5S (even a 4S), my iPhone 4 becomes slow after 5 or more applications in multitasking, which means this would not be my first answer choice. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I don't clear the apps, and I do get the messages.  Every. Darn. Time.