# How to disable iOS 7 warning about mobile data being turned off for an app

Tags: iphone, ios, settings, cellular-data

I use an app that can consume a sizeable amount of bandwidth, so I have disabled mobile data for that app under *Settings* > *Mobile* > *USE MOBILE DATA FOR* > *[App Name]* > *OFF*. The setting works great, and prevents the app from using any mobile data, so it only updates when I'm connected to WiFi.

The only problem is that, now, whenever I start the app, iOS 7 pops up the following modal dialogue:

> Mobile Data is Turned Off for "App Name".
>   You can turn on mobile data for this app in Settings.
>
> [Settings]    [OK]

[image]

This message is so über-modal that you can't even press the Home button before tapping **OK**. It has become very frustrating.

Is there any way to disable the modal warning to remind me that mobile data is turned off for an app?

---

**Edit**: The answer to this problem detailed [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/115535/25461).

Comment: I have several apps where I have turned off mobile data. I know very well that I have done this, so I don't need the phone to tell me this each f*** time I move outside WiFi coverage!! This is the most irritating feature ever.